# How to write a crawler in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

I am working on a ROR application where I need to implement a crawler that crawls other sites and stores data in my database. For example suppose I want to crawl all deals from http://www.snapdeal.com and store them into my database. How to implement this using crawler?

Comment: Just like in any other language. Fetch some HTML, parse it, follow links, store everything in a database.

Comment: You can try [pioneer gem](https://github.com/fl00r/pioneer) while it is still under development

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are couple of options depending upon your usecase.

- [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri) is the RailsCast that will get you started.
- [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is built on top of Nokogiri. See the [Mechanize RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize).
- Screen Scraping with [ScrAPI](http://rubygems.org/gems/scrapi) and the [ScrAPI RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi).
- [Hpricot](http://rubygems.org/gems/hpricot).

I have used combination of Nokogiri and Mechanize for few of my projects and I think they are good options.

Answer (score 3):

You want to take a look at [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). Also from what you mention you probably don't need rails at all.

Comment: he may need web-server at some point to run it and I think then Rails will come to rescue. Off-course there are other web-servers but Rails one is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @bhushan, no from what he mentions there's no reason to think rails would be useful.

Comment: I understand that script would be independent but then how would you couple them with App?

Comment: @bhushan, well if there *were* a rails app to couple it with the only thing they might have in common would be the db config.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio commented, you retrieve pages, parse them, and follow their links. In your case, it sounds like you're more focused on "screen scraping" than crawling deep link networks, so a library like [Scrubyt](https://github.com/scrubber/scrubyt) will be helpful (although progress on it has died out). You can also use a lower-level parsing-focused library like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

Comment: Thanks guys for quick reply.But some sites requires authentication to enter in.So is it possible to crawl such sites? If yes then how?

Comment: It sounds like Scrubyt probably will handle submitting a form and maintaining the resulting session cookies, although I've never tried that.